# AngularJS ViewModel undefined in service

Tags: angularjs, viewmodel, angularjs-factory

I have spent quite sometime on this but seems I am going no where... I am trying to create a model/viewmodel which I am injecting the service but the model object is always undefined.

```
'use strict';

define(['app'], function (app) {
    (function() {
        var taskVm = function(data) {
            this.firstName = data == null ? 'undefined' : (data.firstName == undefined ? '' : data.firstName),
                this.lastName = data == null ? 'undefined' : (data.lastName == undefined ? '' : data.lastName),
                this.contactNumber = data == null ? 'undefined' : (data.contactNumber == undefined ? '' : data.contactNumber),
                this.days = data == null ? 'undefined' : (data.taskStartedOn == undefined ? 1 : new Date().getDate() - new Date(data.taskStartedOn)),
                this.taskName = data == null ? 'undefined' : (data.taskName == undefined ? '' : data.taskName),
                this.taskId = data == null ? 'undefined' : (data.taskId == undefined ? 0 : data.taskId),
                this.processInstanceId = data == null ? 'undefined' : (data.processInstanceId == undefined ? 0 : data.processInstanceId),
                this.passportNumber = data == null ? 'undefined' : (data.passportNumber == undefined ? '' : data.passportNumber)
        };

        taskVm.prototype.setAgentData = function(data) {
            return new taskVm(data)
        };

    taskVm.prototype.object = function() {
        return {
            firstName: this.firstName,
            lastName: this.lastName,
            contactNumber: this.contactNumber,
            days: this.days,
            taskName: this.taskName,
            taskId: this.taskId,
            processInstanceId: this.processInstanceId,
            passportNumber: this.passportNumber
        };

    }
    app.factory('taskVm', [taskVm]);
}());
```

});

this is being inject in service ...

```
'use strict';

define(['app'], function (app) {

    var taskService = function($http, $q, $timeout, config, taskVm) {
        var taskFactory = {}, tasks = [];

        taskFactory.insertTask = function() {};

        taskFactory.getTask = function() {
         return  $http.get(config.serviceBase + config.task.get.taskList, { timeout: 5000, withCredentials: true }).then(
                    function (result) {

                        angular.forEach(result.data.list, function (item) {
                            var currentItem = new taskVm(item);
                            console.log(item);
                            console.log(currentItem);
                        });
                        return result.data;
                    });
                    }

           return taskFactory;
    };

    app.factory('taskService', ['$http', '$q', '$timeout', 'config', 'taskVm', taskService]);
});
```

but the taskVm object is always undefined. Any pointers will be very welcome.

Comment: I think you should return taskVm at the end of your factory service.

Comment: @pasine if I do that I get this ; 
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/undefined/$injector/unpr?p0=taskVmProvider%20%3C-%20taskVm%20%3C-%20taskService%20%3C-%20dataService

Comment: With service you must return a function, with factory you must return an object. Have a look at [this link](http://blog.jdriven.com/2013/03/how-to-create-singleton-angularjs-services-in-4-different-ways/) I always use it when in doubt.

Comment: @pasine thanks got some help from your link and rest was from this link http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/03/17/building-better-models-for-angularjs.aspx